# Keep original file with Gulp

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I just started to use Gulp. This code is used to compress a scss file to css. I can't figure out how to keep one of the css files uncompressed.

**This is what I want it to be:**

```
/assets/css/custom.css
/assets/css/custom.min.css
```

**Code:**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('assets/scss/custom.scss')
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css/'));
});

gulp.task('default',function() {
    gulp.watch('assets/scss/**/*.scss',['styles']);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do is expand your task so that it writes out the uncompressed version, then compresses it, renames it, then finally writes it out again.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('assets/scss/custom.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css/'))
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css/'));
});
```

Note that you'll need to add the [*gulp-rename*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) plugin to your dependencies. You could also use a dedicated minifier (such as [*gulp-minify-css*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css)) rather than the SASS plugin to minify your CSS.

Comment: Are there any benefits of using gulp-minify-css instead?

Comment: The reasons I can think of are: 1) a marginal speed improvement as it doesn't try to compile the already compiled CSS. 2) Futureproofing for if you want to change sass compilers down the line. I don't know if there is a difference in output between the two methods.